# What are the most well known mishnayot (excluding avot)?

Tags: talmud-gemara, mishna

Trying to get a gage on what some of the most well known mishnayot. Which are your personal favorite? Wondering mostly about halacha -- excluding aggadot and masechet Avot.

Comment: Since this is a very subjective question, I think you might be able to get better answers (and not have the question closed) if you reword it to ask something slightly different, like: "Which tractate of Mishna is most quoted in the Talmud?" or something similar

Comment: Welcome to MY Boaz. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the *mishnayot* recited  by many as part of daily *tefillah*.

Off the top of my head:

[Peah 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Peah.1?lang=bi)

[Zevachim Chapter 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Zevachim.5?lang=bi)

Comment: And bameh madlikin and the last one in tamid

Comment: @Heshy Although those are weekly rather than daily